# C++ Segmentation fault in initalization of linked list

Tags: c++

I'm preparing for my CS final next week and I am trying to put together various different programs to study off of (this is not me getting you guys to do my homework).

Anyways, the program I am making now is supposed to modify a linked list in various ways (insert node, append node, reverse list, etc.)

My current problem is with initializing the list.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 //linkedlist.h
#pragma once

struct Node
{
    int datum;
    Node* next;
};

class linkedlist
{
private:
  Node* head;
  Node* duplicateLinkedList(const Node* pOldHead)const;
public:
  unsigned int memberCount()const;
  void insertNode(int x);
  void removeNode(int x);
  void printNode()const;
  void appendNode(int x);
  void initList();
};


//linkedlist.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlist.h"
using namespace std;

//Segmentation fault occurs in here
void linkedlist::initList()
{
  head->datum = 0;
  head->next = NULL;
}
```

I simply wish to initialize the list, but instead I am getting a segmentation fault. I recognize that I could use a default constructor, but this is the format we have been using in class. I can provide more code if needed, but I believe this is sufficient.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to assign a value to head. It is uninitalized.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger to see which line you get the seg fault on?

Comment: `head->next = NULL;` It is evident that `head` is nullptr thus dereferencing it is a segfault.

Comment: @AdamMenz - you _hope_ it's a null pointer and that it doesn't, for example, point to some memory location accessible to the program, like the stack.

Comment: @Arunas: yes ecactly. it is not initialized.

Comment: What do you mean head is not initialized? Isn't that what setting the datum and next fields are doing?

Comment: We mean that head is a pointer that points to an invalid address in memory. So trying ti access that memory through this pointer is Undefined Behavior. The correct way and safest one: 1- Initialize pointer before using it. 2- Don't dereference a `nullptr` ( pointer that points to NULL address: 0x00000000) or an un-initialized one.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I must initial head before I can initialize the datum and next fields. Right?

Comment: the head only is sufficient. however you cannot and there's no need to initialize `datum` and `next` Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dereferencig an un-initialized pointer: `head->next = NULL;` and `head->datum = 0;`.

To initialize your list you can:

```
struct Node
{
    int datum{};
    Node* next{nullptr};
};
```

And in

```
void linkedlist::initList(){
    head = nullptr;
    //head->datum = 0; don't do this becuase head is nullptr
    //head->next = NULL; // don't do this head is nullptr.
}
```